# justifyContent with createStyles in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a toolbar where I am using 2 icons that appear on the left end. Currently, I am using this styling method:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
    },
    appBar: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
      marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    },
    drawer: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
    },
    drawerPaper: {
      width: drawerWidth,
    },

    panelheaderRight: {
      marginRight: 0,
      right: 0,
    },
    toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
    content: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    // justifyContent: spaceBetween,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
  }),
);
```

I want the icons to appear on the right end. If I add a separate css file with this, it works:

```
.toolbar-class{
    justify-content:space-between;
    }
```

but I want to use it inside the `createStyles`. There's no 'space-between' option in createStyles. This is how a portion of my component looks like:

```
<AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar className="toolbar-class">
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Al
          </Typography>
          <div className="panelheaderRight">
            <NotificationsIcon />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            {/* <ExitToAppIcon onClick={() =>
            <ExitToAppIcon onClick={logout}></ExitToAppIcon>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
```

Is there any way I can move the icons to the left using `createStyles`and without adding a separate css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notice points:

- Change `justify-content` to `justifyContent`, and value as string.
- No need to use `createStyels` for `makeStyles`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  toolBar: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  ...
...
```

```
<Toolbar className={classes.toolBar}>
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help. It just brings the logos towards the left, with the text. Maybe because now I'm using two ```toolBar``` in useStyles

Comment: @a125 Try to make it unique, I just pointed out the fault in your code.